# Lesti's FPC not working with Fishpig get post collection

Tags: magento, fishpig, lesti-fpc

I've developed a magento website with the fishpig extension, and as soon as I turned on my Lesti's FPC, i got a white page without any errors on the homepage.

I've managed to trace the error down to the post collection, but I don't know how to fix this issue. Someone had any experience with this?

This is what my post collection looks like:

```
<?php $posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
   ->addPostTypeFilter('sliders')
   ->load(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this error has nothing to do with Lesti FPC. If you have a white page without any errors, this just means that an error has occured but your PHP error display settings prevent it from being displayed. To display the error, open up your Magento index.php file and uncomment the following line:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will reveal the PHP error message. That being said, your issue will probably be fixed by performing the following steps:

1. Upgrade [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) to the latest version. Also update any add-on extensions for Magento WordPress Integration.
2. Check System > Configuration > WordPress for any errors/warnings and fix every single one.
3. Check var/log/ for a wordpress.log file. Delete this file and then go back to the page that triggers the error. See whether any new errors are added to the file.

Please perform these 3 steps (these steps should be followed for any error with Magento WordPress Integration) and see whether the error persists. If the error does remain after following these steps, please update your question with the specific error message (but only after following these 3 steps).

Comment: Thanks for your response Ben,
I've been working with fishpig for quite some time now and I'm aware of these 3 debugging steps. All my plugins and add-ons are up-to-date (multisite, TEC, Post types and ACF) . Also my error reporting is active.

But once I turn on full page cache, I see my site for 1 refresh, and when I refresh again, I just get a white page. Like FPC Isn't able to cache my page.

When I remove all fishpig related code from this page, it does get cached right.

Comment: Hi Koen, If you contact me through https://fishpig.co.uk/contact-us/ with your server FTP details, I'm sure I can debug and fix the issue for you.